# How to draw the trajectories of the solutions in the canonical basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, proof-explanation

I'm trying to understand the steps to solve this exercise:

> Consider the following differential system $$\begin{cases}{x'=-2 x-y} \\ {y'=3 x+y}\end{cases}$$
> Draw the trajectories of the solutions in the canonical basis.

Here is the solution given by my professor:

> In the basis $\left \{\begin{pmatrix}2 \\ -3 \\ \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ \sqrt 3 \\ \end{pmatrix} \right \}$, we have to solve $$\begin{bmatrix}f' \\ g' \\ \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} -\dfrac{1}{2} & \dfrac{\sqrt 3}{2} \\ -\dfrac{\sqrt 3}{2} & -\dfrac{1}{2} \\ \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}f \\ g \\ \end{bmatrix}$$
>
> Setting $z = f + i g$, we have to solve $$z' = \left  (-\frac{1}{2} - i \frac{\sqrt 3}{2} \right)z$$

---

We have $$\begin{bmatrix}x' \\ y' \\ \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} -2 & -1 \\ 3 & 1 \\ \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \\ \end{bmatrix}$$

The characteristic polynomial has two complex roots $$\lambda = -\frac{1}{2} \pm i \frac{\sqrt 3}{2}$$

Could you please explain how to come up with the basis $\left \{\begin{pmatrix}2 \\ -3 \\ \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ \sqrt 3 \\ \end{pmatrix} \right \}$?

Thank you so much for your help!

---

**Update:** I include the screenshot of solution.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Note that the chosen basis preserves the orientation, the transformation is by scaling with positive factors and shearing, no reflection required. Then the wrong factor leads to a wrong orientation of the spiral. Test on the original equations: The angle increment over time $$r^2d\phi=x\,dy-y\,dx=(x(3x+y)-y(-2x-y))dt=(3x^2+3xy+y^2)dt$$ has a positive definite factor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are the real and imaginary part of one of the complex eigenvectors.

The problem that is tried to solve with this construction is that in the diagonalization you get complex numbers on the diagonal. If you wanted to draw this you would have to use 4 real dimensions. Fortunately, a system over the reals also has purely real solutions, so that you can leave out all solutions not inside the real plane.

$\newcommand{\myvec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}\newcommand{\va}{\myvec{a}}\newcommand{\vb}{\myvec{b}}\newcommand{\mA}{\mathfrak{A}}$
It is a question of taste if you take one basis solution $(\va+i\vb)e^{(\alpha+i\beta)t}$, $(\va+i\vb)$ an eigenvector to the eigenvalue $(α+iβ)$ and take real and imaginary part of it
$$
e^{αt}(\va\cos(βt)-\vb\sin(βt)),e^{αt}(\va\sin(βt)+\vb\cos(βt))
$$
or take the long way around in transforming the system to the adapted basis $(\va,\vb)$ where then the system matrix is $\pmatrix{α&β\\-β&α}$ and then compute its exponential $e^{αt}\pmatrix{\cos(βt)&\sin(βt)\\-\sin(βt)&\cos(βt)}$ via any means.

---

You get the same real basis solutions from the complex conjugate pair of eigenvalue $(α-iβ)$ and its eigenvector $(\va-i\vb)$.

---

Comparing the parts in $\mA(\va+i\vb)=(α+iβ)(\va+i\vb)$ gives $\mA\va=α\va-β\vb$ and $\mA\vb=β\va+α\vb$. Then any solution $y(t)=u(t)\va+v(t)\vb$ of $\myvec y'=\mA \myvec y$ leads to component equations
\begin{align}
u'(t)&=αu(t)+βv(t)\\
v'(t)&=-βu(t)+αv(t)\\
\hline
(u+iv)'&=(α-iβ)(u+iv)
\end{align}
so that indeed in the computations of your professor there appears some sign confusion.

Comment: The eigenspace associated with $-\dfrac{1}{2} + i \dfrac{\sqrt 3}{2}$ is generated by two vectors $\begin{pmatrix}-2 \\ 3+i\sqrt 3 \\ \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} -3+i\sqrt 3 \\ 6 \\ \end{pmatrix}$. If I choose $\begin{pmatrix}-2+i0 \\ 3+i\sqrt 3 \\ \end{pmatrix}$, should the basis be $\left \{\begin{pmatrix}-2 \\ 3 \\ \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ \sqrt 3 \\ \end{pmatrix} \right \}$ rather than $\left \{\begin{pmatrix}2 \\ -3 \\ \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ \sqrt 3 \\ \end{pmatrix} \right \}$?

Comment: The eigenspaces are one-dimensional, the two vectors are complex multiples of each other, you can also multiply both with $-1$. That you get this sign difference tells you, as does the factor in the complexified equation, that your professor chose the other eigenvalue for this construction. Both are valid.

Comment: If I multiply $\begin{pmatrix}-2+i0 \\ 3+i\sqrt 3 \\ \end{pmatrix}$ by $-1$, I get $\begin{pmatrix}2+i0 \\ -3-i\sqrt 3 \\ \end{pmatrix}$ and thus the basis is $\left \{\begin{pmatrix}2 \\ -3 \\ \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ -\sqrt 3 \\ \end{pmatrix} \right \}$. This is still different from the one given by my professor. Could you please explain more?

Comment: Your professor used the other eigenvalue $-\dfrac{1}{2} - i \dfrac{\sqrt 3}{2}$, which is conjugate complex and thus has a conjugate complex eigenvector leading to the other sign combination in the pair of real and imaginary part vectors.

Comment: If he chooses $-\dfrac{1}{2} - i \dfrac{\sqrt 3}{2}$ to construct the basis, should the equation be $z' = \left  (-\frac{1}{2} + i \frac{\sqrt 3}{2} \right)z$ rather than $z' = \left  (-\frac{1}{2} - i \frac{\sqrt 3}{2} \right)z$?

Comment: In his solution, $\begin{bmatrix} \alpha & \beta \\ -\beta & -\alpha \\ \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} -\dfrac{1}{2} & \dfrac{\sqrt 3}{2} \\ -\dfrac{\sqrt 3}{2} & -\dfrac{1}{2} \\ \end{bmatrix}$, I think he choose $-\dfrac{1}{2} + i \dfrac{\sqrt 3}{2}$ to construct the basis, not $-\dfrac{1}{2} - i \dfrac{\sqrt 3}{2}$. :(

Comment: I added a more abstract calculation, and yes, you end up with the conjugate eigenvalue as the factor.

Comment: I've just included the screenshot of the solution for the sake of clarity :)

Comment: Please confirm if my understanding is correct! To have equation $\begin{bmatrix}f' \\ g' \\ \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} -\dfrac{1}{2} & \dfrac{\sqrt 3}{2} \\ -\dfrac{\sqrt 3}{2} & -\dfrac{1}{2} \\ \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}f \\ g \\ \end{bmatrix}$ and $z' = \left  (-\frac{1}{2} - i \frac{\sqrt 3}{2} \right)z$, he must have chosen $\left \{\begin{pmatrix}-2 \\ 3 \\ \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ \sqrt 3 \\ \end{pmatrix} \right \}$, not $\left \{\begin{pmatrix}2 \\ -3 \\ \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ \sqrt 3 \\ \end{pmatrix} \right \}$. Hence there is a typo in his solution.

Comment: Yes, or the sign error is in computing the matrix, where the signs on the anti-diagonal would have to be switched.

Comment: If we want to use my professor's basis, we have to use $\begin{bmatrix}f' \\ g' \\ \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} -\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{\sqrt 3}{2} \\ \frac{\sqrt 3}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} \\ \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}f \\ g \\ \end{bmatrix}$ and $z' = \left  (-\frac{1}{2} + i \frac{\sqrt 3}{2} \right)z$, not $\begin{bmatrix}f' \\ g' \\ \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} -\frac{1}{2} & \frac{\sqrt 3}{2} \\ -\frac{\sqrt 3}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} \\ \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}f \\ g \\ \end{bmatrix}$ and $z' = \left  (-\frac{1}{2} - i \frac{\sqrt 3}{2} \right)z$, right?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant.

Comment: Thank you so much for your dedicated support and patience with me! I'm really grateful to you. This is my preparation for the final exam taking in a few days.